# parfor not printing

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am running a small script with a parfor loop. The script starts with the followin line:

```
parfor i=1:length(vX)
    fprintf('%d/%d\n',i,length(X));
    ...
```

So apparently I should see printouts right away. When I run it with a pool of two workers, opened by `matlabpool(2)`, I see **no** printout. When I close the workers, keeping the parfor loop, I see printouts but only when I hit ctrl-c. When I change the `parfor` into a regular `for` I see the output. Note that I never saw the loop run to completion as it is quite long, but the printout is the second line the script and should happen immediately, unless there is some buffer-flushing issue I am not aware of in matlab.
What is happening??

Comment: Does this mean you hit ctrl-c quite immediately? How long do you wait for an output to appear in the console? Does the `parfor` loop ever complete?

Comment: No, I wait for a few seconds and then hit ctrl-c. The printout should be immediate, though.
I'll add this info to the question.

Comment: Maybe there is kind of lock on the `stdout` along a `parfor`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the delay is due to the overhead of setting up a `parfor` loop.

In my experience it can take several, up to 15, seconds just to initialize the loop. This is particularly true when the code in my a loop uses variables with large memory footprints, as the variables must be copied to the workers.

The copying of data between workers is done over the network and a basic network activity monitor should reveal this activity. I find it useful to determine how much of my `parfor` execution time is getting eaten up initializing the workers.

I use `fprintf` all the time in my `parfor` loops; however, I try to be creative about the generated output as the loops iterations are not sequentially.

If all you are looking for is a progress indicator check out: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32101-progress-monitor-progress-bar-that-works-with-parfor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried for months to find a solution. But in the end I just resorted to using

```
disp(['text ',num2str(variable));
```